# Did the Elder Wand's power in Draco's wand go back to the original Elder Wand once Harry owned both of them?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

I'll try to explain the question as best as I can, for those who are still confused about what really happened with the Elder Wand:

When Draco disarms Dumbledore on the Astronomy Tower, the actual Elder Wand doesn't go to Draco (it stays with Dumbledore in his tomb), but the power does go to Draco's wand.

> "The Elder Wand recognized a new master before Dumbledore died, someone who never even laid a hand on it. The new master removed the wand from Dumbledore against his will, never realizing exactly what he had done, or that the world's most dangerous wand had given him its allegiance..."

When Harry gets the Elder Wand from Malfoy, he gets the wand with the Elder Wand's power.

Voldemort takes the original wand from Dumbledore's grave- but that doesn't give him the actual power of it.

> "I stole the wand from its last master's tomb! I removed it against the last master's wishes! Its power is mine!"
>
> "You still don't get it, Riddle, do you? Possessing the wand isn't enough! Holding it, using it, doesn't make it really yours."

So Harry disarms Voldemort, and gets the original Elder Wand- as the ex-Voldemort wand, and the Elder Wand's power as the ex-Draco's wand.

Now that Harry has both wands, would the "power" recognize the "original" wand and reunite with it, leaving Draco's wand powerless?

I would think that the wand wouldn't reunite with the power, because the wand's owner didn't defeat the owner of the Elder Wand's power.

But then Harry mends his wand with the Elder Wand, and it seems as if the Elder Wand got it's power back.

> He laid the broken wand upon the headmaster's desk, touched it with the very tip of the Elder Wand, and said, "Reparo."

So what's happening? Why would the Elder Wand's power go back to the Elder Wand itself?

Comment: I don't have the faintest idea what you're asking. There certainly isn't any evidence of a transfer of power between wands, regardless of who owns them or how many wands that have allegiance of.

Comment: I'm confused where you're getting the idea that the power is transferred with the wand.  Yes yes, the wand chooses the wizard, but it's the allegiance that gets transferred, not the power.

Comment: @Foon- The power and allegiance of the wand are basically the same thing. When the allegiance changes, the power transfers too.

Comment: The power never leaves the Elder Wand into another wand. You're combing allegiance and power which has led to your confusion.

Comment: FWIW because of the above I don't think this is close worthy for "unclear". The question is just based off of a false premise.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot- Ok I got it now. Draco's wand doesn't have any extra power, but it still masters the elder wand

Comment: I believe Draco masters the Elder Wand not his wand.

Comment: It's like a BOGOF for Harry isn't it? By disarming Draco, Harry gets Draco's wand (physical and allegiance) PLUS (unknowingly) wins the allegiance of the Elder Wand. Later on Voldemort gets the physical wand, but doesn't have its allegiance, so it works like any other un-won wand for him.

Comment: You could have dozens of potential wands allied to you, but without having the physical wand, you can't make use of their power. And *vice versa* — you could have dozens of wands, but if you haven't won their allegiance they won't work to their full potential for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The physical wand and its 'power's never separate.

If you believe Ollivander's view of wandlore, only the master of a wand can use it to its full extent.

When Voldemort takes the Elder Wand from Dumbledore's grave, he has the wand with power intact, but cannot access its full power as Draco is its master.

When Harry defeats Draco, he gains mastery of the Elder Wand, but doesn't physically possess it.

Once Voldemort is defeated and Harry has hold of the Elder Wand, it 'recognises' him and he can use it's full power to repair his Phoenix-feather wand.

Comment: So Voldemort actually had the power of the Elder Wand, But Harry had the mastery of it? What's the difference?

Comment: Wand had the power, but locked up and not (fully) accessible to anyone who held it, unless they were also recognised as the master. Think biometric lock that updates if you defeat the current owner.